# Why did Green Goblin ask Aunt May to complete the prayer?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In Spiderman (2002), when Green Goblin attacked Aunt May, she was chanting a prayer. Green Goblin asked Aunt May to complete the prayer before attacking her. Why did he do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Aunt May was praying. The ending of the prayer is "deliver us from evil," and the Goblin, being the sadistic ***evil*** bastard he is, wanted Aunt May to finish the prayer as a twisted sick joke, or simply put - irony.

Comment: I know the scene is supposed to be scary and make you think "Poor dear Aunt May", it always seemed kinda funny to me. "Last night, while I was praying, a flying green man with yellow eyes came in through the wall and asked me to finish the prayer, then left."

Comment: Lol that indeed is funny....the way you say it

Comment: I always laugh when I see that scene. My brother and I often used it as a kind of meme in our inside jokes.

Comment: "And he's wearing that dumb Power Rangers mask, but he's scarier without it on..."

Comment: The replies to this awnser are so funny xD

Comment: He's trying to imply even god wouldn't save her from evil which is goblin